# How to print a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, assembly, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

hi i have implemented a bst in mips and i need to print this tree.
Each node has following four information

- its value
- parent's address
- left child's address
- right child's address

i should print the tree in the following format.
(x means no child)

```
12

8-16

x-9  13-17

x-x  x-11 x-x  x-x
```

Could you please suggest a way to implement this print method?

Comment: Try using [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  Also is this homework? :-)

Comment: yes this is an homework to be done in "mips asesmbly".I am not asking you to write code for me i just ask a way to do this.

Comment: @JamesAndres how is a high-level program that uses it's own format help,since he's using assembly?

Comment: could you post your implementation?There is no way we can help you without knowing that.Also, James Andres just suggested that you tag the question as homework, driven by your saying 'I need'

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about MIPS.  Yes, GraphViz doesn't make much sense in that context. My assembly knowledge isn't great so I'm afraid I won't be of much use here :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering in which you are printing the tree is a breadth-first (level-by-level) traversal.  One option would be as follows: maintain a work list, initially seeded with the root of the tree.  Then, repeatedly dequeue from the work list, print the current element (or x if none is present), then add the two children to the work list.  You would need some way to track when you're done traversing the tree, perhaps by counting the number of nodes first and stopping once you've printed that many nodes.

That said, since you're doing this in MIPS, one simpler option is to linearize the tree into an array, then print the array.  If you number the nodes in a fashion similar to how you number the nodes in an implicit binary heap, you can recursively/iteratively walk the tree, fill in the array with the tree nodes, then walk over the array printing everything out.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you need to print level by level of your binary tree, the most obivous way to print the information is to traverse the tree using breadth-first search method.
The rest is straightforward and shouldn't be a problem. :)